# Creating multicolumns or multirows in a WinForms grid

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I want to create a gridView in WinForms, that is able to obtain columns containing subcolumns. Row elements should be able to fill multiple rows.

This is an example code

```
    public partial class Frm : Form
{
    public Frm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridView.DataSource = FillTable(); // set the table
    }

    private DataTable FillTable() // set some example data
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

        tbl.Columns.Add("Col 1", typeof(int));
        tbl.Columns.Add("Col 2", typeof(string));
        tbl.Columns.Add("Col 3", typeof(bool));

        tbl.Rows.Add(1, "Val 1", true);
        tbl.Rows.Add(2, "Val 2", false);
        tbl.Rows.Add(3, "Val 3", true);
        tbl.Rows.Add(4, "Val 4", false);
        tbl.Rows.Add(5, "Val 5", true);

        return tbl;
    }
}
```

And this code results in

[image: current gridView]

so what I want is something like this

[image: desired gridView]

Some rows or columns should be bigger than "having a cell size of 1,1".

Is it possible to obtain this by code? Painting a grid wouldn't be the best solution, when resizing a column or something like that.

Comment: Yes, its possible but I think the answer is too broad for [so]. Basically you have to override the DataGridView `OnPaint` method and draw the headers by yourself.

Comment: If you need advanced functionality such as this, you will have to handle it yourself.  Or find a 3rd party control that does it for you.  But all of that is outside the scope of a SO Q&A, as @Pikoh stated.

Comment: And even WPF is not able to achieve that?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is two create two subclasses of DataGridViewRowHeaderCell.

The NoPaintHeaderCell is a DataGridViewHeaderCell that is like any other DataGridViewHeaderCell, but does not paint anything.

The MultiColumnHeaderCell is a DataGridViewHeaderCell that paints all Headers starting at the location of the cell, inclusive all NoPaintHeaderCells that are on the right side of the MultiColumnHeaderCell

In your example column 2 would get a MultiColumnHeaderCell and column 3 a NoPaintHeaderCell. When the MultiColumnHeaderCell of column 2 needs to be painted, it detects which kind of header cells are on the right of it. Then it decides to paint all cells as if it was one big cell.

So MultiColumnHeaderCell overrides [DataGridViewHeaderCell.Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewheadercell.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
    Rectangle clipBounds,
    Rectangle cellBounds, 
    int rowIndex,
    DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState, 
    object value, 
    object formattedValue,
    string errorText, 
    DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
    DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
    DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
{
     // adjust clipbounds and cellbounds, such that it paints itself + 
     // the area of the NoPaintCells directly on the right.
     base.Paint(adjustedClipBounds, adjustedCellBounds, ...);
}
```

See the source code of [DataGridViewHeaderCell.Paint](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewHeaderCell@cs/1305376/DataGridViewHeaderCell@cs). You'll see a code snippet:

```
  if (DataGridViewCell.PaintBorder(paintParts))
  {
      PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle);
  }
```

Because you adjusted the clipBounds and the cellBounds you don't have to override [DataGridViewCellHeader.PaintBorder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.paintborder(v=vs.110).aspx)

The NoPaintHeaderCell does not do anything when it paints.